# Not able to connect to Elasticsearch from docker container (node.js client)

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have set up an elasticsearch/kibana docker configuration and I want to connect to elasticsearch from inside of a docker container using the @elastic/elasticsearch client for node. However, the connection is "timing out".

The project is taken with inspiration from Patrick Triest : https://blog.patricktriest.com/text-search-docker-elasticsearch/

However, I have made some modification in order to connect kibana, use a newer ES image and the new elasticsearch node client.

I am using the following docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    container_name: mp-backend
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "9229:9229"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=local
      - ES_HOST=elasticsearch
      - PORT=3000

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "http.cors.allow-origin=*"
      - "http.cors.enabled=true"
      - "http.cors.allow-headers=X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization"
      - "http.cors.allow-credentials=true"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.5.1
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - elastic
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

When building/ bringing the container up, I able to get a response from ES: curl -XGET "localhost:9200", "you know, for search"... And kibana is running and able to connect to the index.

I have the following file located in the backend container (connection.js):

```
const { Client } = require("@elastic/elasticsearch");

const client = new Client({ node: "http://localhost:9200" });

/*Check the elasticsearch connection */
async function health() {
  let connected = false;
  while (!connected) {
    console.log("Connecting to Elasticsearch");
    try {
      const health = await client.cluster.health({});
      connected = true;
      console.log(health.body);
      return health;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("ES Connection Failed", err);
    }
  }
}

health();
```

If I run it outside of the container then I get the expected response:

> node server/connection.js

```
Connecting to Elasticsearch
{
  cluster_name: 'es-docker-cluster',
  status: 'yellow',
  timed_out: false,
  number_of_nodes: 1,
  number_of_data_nodes: 1,
  active_primary_shards: 7,
  active_shards: 7,
  relocating_shards: 0,
  initializing_shards: 0,
  unassigned_shards: 3,
  delayed_unassigned_shards: 0,
  number_of_pending_tasks: 0,
  number_of_in_flight_fetch: 0,
  task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis: 0,
  active_shards_percent_as_number: 70
}
```

However, if I run it inside of the container:

> docker exec mp-backend "node" "server/connection.js"

Then I get the following response:

```
Connecting to Elasticsearch
ES Connection Failed ConnectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
    at onResponse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Transport.js:214:13)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Connection.js:98:9)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:415:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  name: 'ConnectionError',
  meta: {
    body: null,
    statusCode: null,
    headers: null,
    warnings: null,
    meta: {
      context: null,
      request: [Object],
      name: 'elasticsearch-js',
      connection: [Object],
      attempts: 3,
      aborted: false
    }
  }
}
```

So, I tried changing the client connection to (I read somewhere that this might help):

> const client = new Client({ node: "http://172.24.0.1:9200" });

Then I am just "stuck" waiting for a response. Only one console.log of "Connecting to Elasticsearch"

I am using the following version:

```
"@elastic/elasticsearch": "7.5.1"
```

As you probably see, I do not have a full grasp of what is happening here... I have also tried to add:

```
links:
  - elasticsearch
networks:
  - elastic
```

To the api service, without any luck.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Thank you in advance :)

**EDIT:**

I did a "docker network inspect" on the network with *_elastic. There I see the following:

```
"IPAM": {
    "Driver": "default",
    "Options": null,
    "Config": [
        {
            "Subnet": "172.22.0.0/16",
            "Gateway": "172.22.0.1"
        }
    ]
},
```

Changing the client to connect to the "GateWay" Ip:

```
const client = new Client({ node: "http://172.22.0.1:9200" });
```

Then it works! I am still wondering why as this was just "trial and error" Is there any way to obtain this Ip without having to inspect the network?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Docker, `localhost` (or the corresponding IPv4 address 127.0.0.1, or the corresponding IPv6 address ::1) generally means "this container"; you can't use that host name to access services running in another container.

In a Compose-based setup, the names of the `services:` blocks (`api`, `elasticsearch`, `kibana`) are usable as host names.  The caveat is that all of the services have to be on the same Docker-internal network.  Compose creates one for you and attaches containers to it by default.  (In your example `api` is on the `default` network but the other two containers are on a separate `elastic` network.)  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation has some more details.

So to make this work, you need to tell your client code to honor the environment variable you're setting that points at Elasticsearch

```js
const esHost = process.env.ES_HOST || 'localhost';
const esUrl = 'http://' + esHost + ':9200';
const client = new Client({ node: esUrl });
```

In your `docker-compose.yml` file delete all of the `networks:` blocks to use the provided `default` network.  (While you're there, `links:` is unnecessary and Compose provides reasonable `container_name:` for you; `api` can reasonably `depends_on: [elasticsearch]`.)

Since we've provided a fallback for `$ES_HOST`, if you're working in a host development environment, it will default to using `localhost`; outside of Docker where it means "the current host" it will reach the published port of the Elasticsearch container.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation David, that works perfectly!

Comment: I have the same problem. I followed the steps above but I am getting "TimeoutError:request timed out" why is that so?